# Examples for search graph using scipy

Tags: python, scipy, graph-theory

I am having a hard time finding tutorials/examples of how to use and get the path of various search algorithms in [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csgraph.shortest_path.html).

The most common one appearing in google is [this one](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/scipy/scipy_csgraph.htm) where the example has some error at the end with brackets.

```
from scipy.sparse.csgraph import dijkstra
distances, predecessors = dijkstra(graph, indices = i1, return_predecessors = True)
path = []
i = i2

while i != i1:
   path.append(word_list[i])
   i = predecessors[i]

path.append(word_list[i1])
print path[::-1]i2]
```

I don't have the input so I couldn't replicate it but I think just removing i2] works.

The main question I have is how to search the graph where all the indices are calculated, instead of giving it `indices=i1`, which is an optional parameter.  Likewise, how to use the Floyd-Warshall method and get the path from any `i,j` index to any other `i,j` index. Part of my confusion is the lack of description in what the predecessors matrix really is, and how to parse through it.

Are there more thorough tutorials, or could someone give some easy examples to comb through and understand?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I will use this undirected graph as example:

[image]

First we need the matrix representing the distances from node i to j:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse.csgraph import shortest_path

M = np.array([[ 0,  7,  9,  0, 0, 14],
              [ 7,  0, 10, 15, 0,  0],
              [ 9, 10,  0, 11, 0,  2],
              [ 0, 15, 11,  0, 6,  0],
              [ 0,  0,  0,  6, 0,  9],
              [14,  0,  2,  0, 9,  0]])
```

Now we call

```
D, Pr = shortest_path(M, directed=False, method='FW', return_predecessors=True)
```

Here `D` is the shortest-distances-matrix and `Pr` is the predecessors-matrix. `D[i, j]` gives the shortest distance from node i to node j and `Pr[i, j]` gives the index of the previous node in the shortest path from point i to point j. Pr[i,j] = -9999 if there isn't any path from node i to node j. With `method='FW'` we choose the Floyd-Warshall algorithm.

And finally we can use the predecessors-matrix to define a function to get the list of the nodes from the shortest path from node i to node j:

```
def get_path(Pr, i, j):
    path = [j]
    k = j
    while Pr[i, k] != -9999:
        path.append(Pr[i, k])
        k = Pr[i, k]
    return path[::-1]
```

To get the shortest Path from Node 0 to 4:

```
In [16]: get_path(Pr,0,4)
Out[16]: [0, 2, 5, 4]

In [17]: D[0,4]
Out[17]: 20.0
```

---

**Edit**: It may be worth to take a look at the [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/) package:

```py
import networkx as nx

G = nx.from_numpy_array(M) # M is the adjacency matrix from above
```

```py
In [14]: nx.shortest_path(G, 0, 4, weight='weight')
Out[14]: [0, 2, 5, 4]

In [15]: nx.shortest_path_length(G, 0, 4, weight='weight')
Out[15]: 20
```

Comment: This is the second time you've helped, thank you!.  As a followup to the predecessors matrix so that I am understanding correctly, it seems the path from node 0 to 4 is passed as i and j, then k is set to j(4), so the pair [i,k] is [0,4], in the Pr.  This value is 5.  Is 5 then the node right before the last one, and you work backwards?

Comment: @user1938107 Exactly!

Comment: Anyone finding this and wondering, the second array in the matrix should read:
`[7, 0, 10, 15, 0, 0]`
Instead of
`[7, 0, 9, 15, 0, 0]`

Also, I'm not certain, but should the distances to un-connected nodes be 0 or some infinitely large number? Setting it to zero seems to indicate that the distance is the same as that to the source node.

Comment: @eugene Thanks for the hint, I fixed the typo. An adjacency matrix A contains only 1s and 0s. When there's no edge connecting node i and j, then A[i,j] = 0. A distance matrix is just a weighted adjacency matrix, so the distance for un-connected nodes should be 0.